# How to spyon jquery function inside angular directive in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Directive

```
         link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {    

            element.mouseover(function() {
                $(element).tooltip('show');
            });
            $(element).hover(MuiBootstrap.adjustTooltips);
        }
```

Jasmine test

```
       it('should show tooltip on mouseover', function () {
         var spy = spyOn(element, 'mouseover');
         $(element).trigger('mouseover');
         expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
       });
```

Above jasmine test is getting failed
     Error: Uncaught Expected spy tooltip to have been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work since you try to spy on `mouseover` method which is called only once in directive `link` function and you install spy on this method after it has been already called - the moment you install spy spied function already has been called so spy is not aware of this.
I suggest to not test if `mouseover` itself is called but if `mouseover` callback is called when event is triggered - which you actually do because you spy on `tooltip` method (your error message suggests that you spy on tooltip method). So just remove this test since it's pointles. I assume you want to test if mouseover callback has been called not if `mouseover` method has been called - these two are not the same.

**Answer update:**
To test mouseover callback you can define this callback on directive scope:

```
link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {    
    scope.mouseoverCallback = function() {
        $(element).tooltip('show');
    };
    element.mouseover(scope.mouseoverCallback);
}
```

and then install spy directly on it:

```
 it('should call mouseover callback', function () {
     var yourDirectiveScope = element.scope();
     var spy = spyOn(yourDirectiveScope, 'mouseoverCallback').and.callThrough();
     element.triggerHandler('mouseover');
     expect(yourDirectiveScope.mouseoverCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

Comment: Not Working.. Err- Uncaught Expected spy mouseover to have been called.

Comment: any idea how to test mouse over callback?